# Automated testing for DialogFlow

Tags: automated-tests, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have developed a bot using DialogFlow/API.ai.

I am trying to include automated testing to test the conversation that I have developed before moving the code to deployment. Are there any frameworks that Dialogflow/API.ai support which can be used for automated testing?

Comment: That would definitely be nice, but I don't know if it's available yet for Dialogflow or Actions on Google. There are gRPC bindings to send/receive audio and you can use code to send/receive clips to verify your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dialogflow does not currently support any testing frameworks.

You could use Dialogflow's v1 query API or v2 detectIntent API to query your agent with responses and retrive answers in sequence to test conversational flows:

- [Dialogflow v1 Query API Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query)
- [Dialogflow v2 detectIntent API Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent)

Comment: This article shows how to do something similar with Alexa: http://www.macadamian.com/2017/10/13/automating-alexa-skill-dialog-testing/ Try applying this idea to Dialogflow's APIs like @matthewayne suggested.

Comment: I wrote a blogpost on automated testing of Dialogflow Fulfillments. Might be useful: https://xebia.com/blog/how-to-automate-testing-for-google-assistant-apps/

Answer (score 3):

Dialogflow is supported by [Botium, the Selenium for Chatbots](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core). It uses the Dialogflow V2 API to send requests and verify responses. The conversation scripts can be maintained in Excel files or plain text files.
It is also possible to download and extract your intents, utterances and conversation structure from Dialogflow and generating the test scripts automatically - [here is a tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/3-steps-setup-automated-testing-for-google-assistant-and-dialogflow-de42937e57c6)

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a new tool to test conversations for Dialogflow automatically named "dialogflow-query-checker":

https://github.com/yoichiro/dialogflow-query-checker

Comment: Account linking is supported with last 1.13 version

Answer (score -1):

Tx, for the info. Is it possible to do account linking with your tool ? My bot need to be logged first before making interaction

Comment: You should know to add comments if you have further questions on any answer given here. Do not add it as an answer.